# Copying a pointer of a pointer (matrix) values in C

Tags: c, matrix, pointer-to-pointer, cop

The problem is the following:
I created a dynamic matrix, using pointer to pointer `matrix1`

I want to create a copy of this matrix into another, `matrix2`

I want to do that so I can mess with `matrix2` without messing with `matrix1`
So I tried to do the following:

```
int main()
{
    int **matrix1, **matrix2, size1 = 10, size2 = 2;
    matrix1 = create_matrix(size1, size2);

    //I want to copy the value of matrix1 into matrixq2 and NOT the index
    **matrix2 = **matrix1
}
```

However the program breaks and show the following: [image: Error]

I understand that by the way it look, it would be easier to use the function `create_matrix` two times, for `matrix1` and another for `matrix2`. But in the way that my original program is that would be too much work, since I do a lot of stuff to have the matrix done. 
Oh, and by the way, I want to avoid using C++, is there is a way to do it without using it? It would be better for me.

the code 'create_matrix' is the following:

```
//The program will read a file with the name of endereco, and create a matrix contPx3 out of it
int ** cria_matrix(char endereco[], int contP)
{
    FILE *fPointer;
    int i, contE, auxIndex, auxNum, **processos, cont_line = 0;
    char line[100];
    bool flag = true, flag2;

    fPointer = fopen(endereco, "r");

//Here the creation of the matrix
    processos = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * contP);
    for (i = 0; i < contP; i++)
        processos[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);



//For now and on, is the rules of how the data will be placed on the matrix
    contP = 0;
    while (!feof(fPointer) && flag)
    {

        memset(&line[0], 'Ì', sizeof(line));
        fgets(line, 100 , fPointer);
//Bassicaly is that in each line there will be 3 numbers only, diveded but as many spaces you want. The numbeer will be placed on the matrix on the determined line they are.
        auxIndex = 0;
        flag2 = false;
        if(line[0] != '#')
            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (line[i] != ' ' && line[i] != '\n' && line[i] != '\0' && line[i] != 'Ì')//&&  line[i] != 'à'
                {
                    auxNum = line[i] - '0';
                    processos[contP][auxIndex] = auxNum;
                    auxIndex++;
                    flag2 = true;

                }
            }

        if (flag2)
            contP++;



        cont_line++;
        if (auxIndex != 3 && auxIndex != 0)
        {
            flag = false;
            printf("ERRO na linha: %d No processo: %d\nProvavelmente mais ou menos que 3 numeros separado por espacos\n", cont_line, contP);
        }

    }
    fclose(fPointer);
    if (!flag)
        system("PAUSE");
    return processos;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675800/how-to-copy-matrix-in-c

Comment: You are not posting full code.

Comment: @parik, that is not a valid dup. The data type there is `T[N][M]`, while here it's `T**`. Blindly applying a solution from there will likely crash the OPs program.

Comment: Also, copy the first level of indirection, not the first element: `memcpy(*matrix2, *matrix1, size1 * size2 * sizeof(int))`. If you defined it correctly, `**matrix1` should be a `int`.

Comment: Finally, you still need to allocate the actual `matrix2`. Currently, it points to trash.

Comment: You really should post `create_matrix` or your question may still be closed.

Comment: I posted the code of `create_matrix`

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2988730

Comment: ok, I just edited.

Comment: Updated my answer to take into account that your buffer is not monolithic and that there is no actual `create_matrix` function.

Comment: @Hirosam You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?s=1|3.1440).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix1` points to the array of row pointers, `*matrix1` is a pointer to an array holding the first row of actual data, and `**matrix1` is the value of first element of the first row. `matrix1` and each of its elements are all dynamically allocated arrays.

`matrix2` is an uninitialized (trash) pointer in the code you have displayed. It has neither the row pointer nor data buffers allocated.

To achieve your desired result, you need to first allocate the elements of `matrix2`, then copy just the data portion of `matrix1` over.

```
int **copy_matrix(int **mat, int size1, int size1)
{
    int row;

    int **res = malloc(size1 * sizeof(int *));
    for(row = 0; row < size1; row++) {
        res[row] = malloc(size2 * sizeof(int));
        memcpy(res[row], mat[row], size2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    return res;
}

...

matrix2 = copy_matrix(matrix1, size1, size2);
```

An alternative would be to allocate a single buffer for the copy. While this is possibly a better way of storing matrices in general, it may not be as useful to you because you will not be able to free the memory of `matrix2` the same way that you do for `matrix1`:

```
int **copy_matrix(int **mat, int size1, int size2)
{
    int row;
    int **res = malloc(size1 * sizeof(int *));
    res[0] = malloc(size1 * size2 * sizeof(int));

    for(row = 0; row < size1; row++) {
        res[row] = res[0] + row * size2;
        memcpy(res[row], mat[row], size2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I believe **matrix1 is the value of the first element, not the address of it.

Comment: Next, I believe your memcpy assumes there are size1 * size2 int values stored at memory location *matrix1. I don't think that's the case. I think there are only size2 int values stored there. I think the memcpy reads out of bounds. Do you agree?

Comment: Unless OP posts `create_matrix` function, I am going with the monolithic data array assumption.

Comment: `create_matrix` function will create the matrix and put values on it. And yes, the matrix is `size1`x`size2`

Comment: @Hirosam. Your code is ambiguous. Please post the actual code of the function in your question.

Comment: Agreed, would like to see the implementation of create_matrix.

Comment: I edit with the full code, now I can understand why you want to see it. Sry for not posting before

Comment: In the first example I would have to return the `res` matrix?

Comment: @Hirosam. My mistake. Fixed both examples. And yes, you'd probably want the first one.

Comment: @MadPhysicist shouldn't  the last example have `res[row] = res[0] + row *size2;` instead of `if(row) res[row] = res[0] + size2;` ? (and second `size1` should probably be `size2`?)

Comment: @deamentiaemundi. Thanks. Fixed on all counts.

Answer (score 1):

How bout this-

```
matrix2 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*size1);
for(int idx = 0; idx < size1; ++idx) {
    matrix2[idx] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size2);
    for(int idx2 = 0; idx2 < size2; ++idx2) {
        matrix2[idx][idx2] = matrix1[idx][idx2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand the difference between copying pointers, taking shallow copies, and taking deep copies.
Consider this

```
struct employee
{
   char *name;
   float salary;
   int payrollid;
}
```

There are now three ways of copying an employee

```
struct employee * emp1;  // points to an employee, set up somehow
struct employee * emp2;  // empty pointer, null or whatever

emp2 = emp1;  // copy pointers. emp1 and emp2 now point to the same object.
```

Pointer copy

```
struct employee  employee1;  // employee, set up
struct employee  employee2;  // uninitalised emplyee

memcpy(&employee2, &employee1, sizeof(struct employee)); // shallow copy
```

Shallow copy

```
struct employee * emp1;  // points to an employee, set up somehow
struct employee * emp2;  // empty pointer, null or whatever

emp2 = copyemployee(emp1);

struct employee *copyemployee(struct employee *e)
{
   struct employee *answer = malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
   if(!answer)
     goto error_exit;
   answer->name = malloc(strlen(e->name) + 1);
   if(!answer->name)
      goto error_exit;
   strcpy(answer>name, e->name);
   answer->salary = e->salary;
   answer->payroolid = e->payrollid;
   return answer;
error_exit:
   /* out of memory handle somehow, usually by returning null
}
```

Deep copy

As you can see, even for a simple structure with only one variable-length field, taking a deep copy is quite a bit of work.
All have their uses, though shallow copies are probably the least useful and most bug prone of the three.

You simply need to assign to a pointer, probably.

Comment: So you went off on a tangent where you talk about structures, which OP does not use, then admitted that you don't really know how that relates to OP's question for sure. Also, your final answer is wrong.

Comment: I can understand what pointer copy is, but shallow and deep copy confuses me.

Comment: @Hirosam. It's a concept that is much more relevant in languages like Java, where pointers are implicit rather than explicit. Deep copy means you copy the pointer-to-rows, and the contents of the rows, while shallow copy means you only copy the ponter-to-rows, but your data buffers are the same (the opposite of what you want).